# Pyspark's sqlContext.read.csv() function is reading more lines than exists in actual .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyspark

I have a CSV file. You can get the file from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13w9Ok0kcvFIZ5WLPD9jyvheuQFTWu-Zk). This file has 20050 rows. Some columns have multi-line text. If I am reading this file using :

```
df = sqlContext.read.csv(FILE, header=True)
```

It is showing 24230 rows. If I set the multi-line option to true, It is showing index out of bounds exception.

What is the best way to read this csv file with exact number of rows. If I read it using pandas `pd.read_csv()` then it is showing exact no. of rows. But I want to read this CSV without using pandas. Thanks.

Any working solution is most welcome.

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

FILE = "file:///home/shivam/gender-classifier-DFE-791531.csv"
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.csv(FILE, header=True)

# Expected output 20050
# Actual Output 24230
print(df.count())
```

Expected output = 20050

Actual Output = 24230

Comment: There could be empty likes if you csv. Post the output of `tail path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

If the multi-line is correctly formatted, use univocity parser. You will end up reading the whole csv into a single executor, so make sure that you have enough memory.

```
spark.read
  .option("parserLib", "univocity")
  .option("multiLine", "true")
  .csv(file.csv)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the count is still returning 20170 lines instead of 20050 lines.